# String to method/function call in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I want to make my rails controller more flexible and try to create some Meta foo for it.

I have a problem with the redirect_to method. Can I convert the "edit_admin_post_path()" method from a string or better read out the controller name and pass it dynamicly?

this is my code for "post" in my Admin::Posts controller.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(edit_admin_post_path(@object)) }
end
```

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand what you want to do, however there are multiple ways to achieve your request. One is

```
what = "post"
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(send("edit_admin_#{what}_path", @object)) }
end
```

Keep in mind, `edit_admin_post_path` is equal to

```
url_for(:controller => "admin/posts", :action => "edit", :id => @object)
```

So you can always do

```
what = "post"
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(url_for(:controller => "admin/#{what.pluralize}", :action => "edit", :id => @object)) }
end
```

or better, if you want to dynamically redirect to the edit action according to current controller, just pass the hash of options.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(:action => "edit", :id => @object) }
end
```